# Add Binding To IIS With PowerShell Without Overwriting Existing

Tags: powershell, iis, octopus-deploy

We use OctopusDeploy to create the website and we use the create website template that is on the community step sites.  I have modified it slightly to ensure that if the website exists it adds the default binding however it is removing all the existing bindings.  Is there a way to simply add a binding to IIS which overwrites if it already exists (or ignores) and doesn't remove all the existing bindings?

The script we currently have is as follows:

```
$bindingInformation = "${bindingIpAddress}:${bindingPort}:${bindingHost}"

$sitePath = ("IIS:\Sites\" + $webSiteName)

$site = Get-Item $sitePath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if (!$site) { 
    Write-Output "Creating web site $webSiteName" 
    $id = (dir iis:\sites | foreach {$_.id} | sort -Descending | select -first 1) + 1
    new-item $sitePath -bindings ($wsBindings[0]) -id $id -physicalPath $webRoot -confirm:$false
} else {
    write-host "Web site $webSiteName already exists"
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $sitePath -Name Bindings -Value ($wsBindings[0])
}
```

It seems this line:

```
        Set-ItemProperty -Path $sitePath -Name Bindings -Value ($wsBindings[0])
```

Is overwriting all existing bindings but I can't seem to find a way around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [New-WebBinding](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790567.aspx) cmdlet:

```powershell
  New-WebBinding `
        -Name $webSiteName `
        -Protocol 'http' `
        -Port $bindingPort `
        -IPAddress $bindingIpAddress `
        -HostHeader $bindingHost
```

And use [Get-WebBinding](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ee790596.aspx) cmdlet to check whether the binding already exists.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `New-WebBinding` as jisaak said, that's mainly for http(s).

If you need to add other types of bindings, you have to use `New-ItemProperty`, instead of `Set-ItemProperty`.

```
New-ItemProperty -path "IIS:\Sites\YourSiteName" `
    -name bindings -value @{protocol="net.pipe";bindingInformation="SiteName"}
```